# Ng-repeat orderBy value

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I order my ng-repeat by the `like_count` in my json?

I have given it a bash but I am clearly missing something.

This is the repeat

```
item(ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:3 | orderBy:like_count)
```

This is the data structure:

```
{
  "image_url" : "bde2cca8323d098edf43389119af7748.jpg",
  "title" : "This is the title",
  "like_count" : "15",
  "creator" : {
    "profile_img" : "john-doe.jpg",
    "username" : "JD",
    "url" : "/John-Doe",
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name" : "Doe",
    "location" : "Sydney, Australia"
  }
}, {
  "image_url" : "bjk23482301232234112d3232345343.jpg",
  "title" : "This is the title",
  "like_count" : "89",
  "creator" : {
    "profile_img" : "Jane-doe.jpg",
    "username" : "JD",
    "url" : "/Jane-Doe",
    "first_name" : "Jane",
    "last_name" : "Doe",
    "location" : "Melbourne, Australia"
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `orderBy:'like_count'` work?

Comment: Is it ordering by the string value?

Comment: `orderBy:'-like_count'` works perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:3 | orderBy:'like_count'
```

Comment: That's just a copy of the comments :)

Comment: Correctness is not the problem! It is correct, but you just copied what I had said in the comments, after OP had mentioned that it was correct! It's a little like cheating :)

Comment: Frnd its not cheating. I didn't comment the answers directly because my reputation is low. So I answer the question directly if I cheated you na sorry guy...

Comment: Hi I'm just wonder if you add few more items to your array will sorting still working in proper way. I'm just asking because  sorting at the moment string instead of int so (4 will be before 50 but after 10000)?

Comment: @parthicool05 Not being able to comment doesn't mean you didn't read them and simple copy the answer. Facts are facts :)